# ¿Cómo mantengo la relación de aspecto en componentes de JPanel?

Tags: java

Estoy diseñando un software en el cual la interfaz gráfica consta de 4 paneles los cuales pertenecen a un panel general. Cada uno de los 4 paneles contiene JLabels, JTextFields y JButtons, el problema está en que las dimensiones me cuadran bien si el ordenador en el que lo ejecuto tiene las mismas pulgadas que el mío...
¿Cómo podría hacer para que se reajustara automáticamente las dimensiones de los componentes de los paneles? (El layout que he utilizado es GridBagLayout).

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Cuando diseñas una interfaz primero piensas en la resolución mínima objetivo que quieres utilizar. Por ejemplo, yo diseño para pc de bajo rendimiento y por tanto mi tamaño mínimo es para una resolución de 800x600 (Que sería lo que windows permite). Cuando es mayor los componentes fluyen con FlowLayout y el espacio entre ellos crece a como los defina dentro de netbeans(Diseño gráficamente). ¿Es la idea que tienes o estoy mal?

Comment: y cuales son las dimensiones que tiene actualmente? pon tu código para que te podamos dar una idea, el gridbag layout es muy flexible

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que quieres deberias crear las relaciones de aspecto segun la resolucion de pantalla, con la clase Toolkit podras obtener las dimensiones de la pantalla principal del sistema en que se este ejecutando. AL crear los diferentes elementos tendras que indicarles que sus dimensiones seran por ejemplo el ancho de la pantalla dividido entre 2 y el largo dividido entre dos, entonces ese elemento tendrias como dimension la mitad de la pantalla en donde se este ejecutando la aplicacion. Espero haberme explicado bien y siento no poder adjuntarte el metodo de la clase que has de utilizar, no te sera dificil encontrar como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Mi problema es que por ejemplo ejecuto el software en un PC de 13 pulgadas y se ven todas las etiquetas, botones, etc bien, porque es sobre el PC que lo he programado. No obstante ejecuto el mismo software en un PC de 15 pulgadas y se ven pequeños, ya que se ha expandido aún más la pantalla. Me gustaría que los componentes de los JPanels se expandieran también.

Voy a probar lo que ha dicho Alexmaister, gracias a todos!